# Magento2 - How to change cart totals label?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, jslayout

I want to modify this label

[image]

Its from "checkout.cart.totals" block in `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`
, and I'm pretty sure its this chunk of code that handles the label

```
<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

so I changed that chunk of code like so:

```
<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I just changed the title from Order Total to Grand Total.

But nothing changed. Front end still shows Order Total. Did I missed something?

Comment: Have you clear cache?

Comment: Nevermind, I know the problem. Its the wrong xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bad.
Using Knockoutjs context debugger, I can see the template is coming from `Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total`. So the right xml would be `magento\vendor\magento\module-tax\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`

and the code to be edited is this:

```
<item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
    <item name="exclTaxLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total Excl. Tax</item>
    <item name="inclTaxLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total Incl. Tax</item>
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total</item>
</item>
```

- **edit:** **Found another way to do it without modifying the magento component.**

I create this file `app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`

with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- UI component customizations -->
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks,It worked for me, i also did the same mistake you did.i was changing in the checkout_cart_index,xml but now i solved it :)

Comment: Thanks @SayyedHasan and zekkai  it works for me. happy coding

Answer (score 3):

You can also change **Order Total** label at

**Core File:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

**Theme File:**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv

Change this

```
"Order Total","Your Custom Title"
```

Comment: I see. However it's not my preferred way because it edits the translation file. Deep deep inside.. the value is still 'Order Total'. Thanks for different approach.